# PDFBOX : java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, numberformatexception

When I'm trying to execute the below code it throws me below error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8#40"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

Code :

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;

public class PDFPerform
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try{
            String sourcePath = "C:\\Users\\347702\\Desktop\\fw4.pdf";
            String destinationPath = "D:\\PDF_FORMS\\filled_fw4.pdf";

            PDDocument document;
            document = PDDocument.load(sourcePath);
            PDAcroForm form = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();


            PDField Field_1= form.getField("f1_09(0)");
            Field_1.getValue();
            System.out.println(Field_1.getValue());
            Field_1.setValue("asdsd");
            System.out.println(Field_1.getFieldType());
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me out the root cause of the above mentioned issue .. 
the mentioned field `f1_09(0)` is of type text but when I set a value to it throws me above error

Thanks

Comment: Please supply the PDF in question.

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly once I updated my `pdfbox.1.7.1` version to `pdfbox1.8.1.jar`