# pdfbox : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1#1"

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using apache pdfbox 2.0.21.

When I'm trying to execute the below code it throws me error like number format exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1#1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.acroFormLegacyMode(PDFMergerUtility.java:1367)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeAcroForm(PDFMergerUtility.java:1176)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.appendDocument(PDFMergerUtility.java:575)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.legacyMergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:459)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:346)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.multipdf.PDFMergerUtility.mergeDocuments(PDFMergerUtility.java:330)
```

Code:

```
      try {
            PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
            Path mergedTempFile = Files.createTempFile("merge_", ".pdf");

            merger.setDestinationFileName(mergedTempFile.toString());

            System.err.println(mergedTempFile.toFile());

            String[] fileArray = { 
                    "D://test//34026-15BN-011-34B.pdf",
                    "D://test//34026-15BN-011-34B comment.pdf"
            };

            List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String name : fileArray) {
                files.add(new File(name));
            }

            for (File file : files) {
                merger.addSource(file);
            }

            merger.mergeDocuments(null);   //On this line it throws error

            System.out.println("Merging Completed...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

There is another related issue posted but it did not help.
[PDFBOX : java.lang.NumberFormatException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742625/pdfbox-java-lang-numberformatexception#)

Please help me on this.

Comment: Sounds like your PDF has a field named "dummyFieldName1#1". Please share your PDFs.

Comment: https://www.filemail.com/d/zkxrejdelsyyapg -- @Tilman Hausherr  Please download file from this link and help me as I have already debug the internal code a lot. But, cannot figure out the cause.

Comment: Hhmmm, here PDFBox assumes it's the only software adding `dummyFieldName` fields and can assume a certain format... clearly a bug of `PDFMergerUtility.acroFormLegacyMode()`.

Comment: @mkl So, is there any workaround for such issue?
If not please let me know where I can raise this defect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug (because "dummyFieldName" is used as a prefix for duplicate fields when merging, and a number is expected as suffix) tracked in [PDFBOX-5257](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5257) and will be fixed in the 2.0.25 release, coming within the next 3 months. Until then, [get a snapshot](https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.25-SNAPSHOT/) which includes the bugfix.

Alternatively, rename the fields so that they don't contain "dummyFieldName", by using `setPartialName()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and taking this scenario into consideration.